# What means "$xx (xx ...)" in ID3v2.4 specification for ETCO frame?

Tags: id3v2, id3-tag

I'm trying to write a ID3v2.4 parser. But I've got stuck with [this part's byte meaning in the `ETCO` frame](https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.4.0-frames.html#etco):

> ```
> Time stamp      $xx (xx ...)
> ```

It couldn't mean some amount of bytes from the first `$xx` till the end of frame, because it represents timestamps, that can be used more than 1 time. So what is it? Maybe I didn't clearly figure out MPEG frames.

I've tried to google it, but there is no info about it.

Comment: Hmm... It seems like $xx (xx ...) in case of time stamps, where it's not logic to go till the frame end, just means $xx xx xx xx, i. e. 32 bit sized num.

Comment: Do you ask for the specific ETCO frame or SYLT? Or what frame type exactly do you mean?

Comment: Your search skills are questionable: see [ID3V2.3, ETCO Frame Event Format Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586097/id3v2-3-etco-frame-event-format-clarification). v2.3 and v2.4 are the same for `ETCO`.